# Python - mount can't resolve selenium module in a container

Tags: python, selenium, docker

I am trying to mount my host computer to my docker container which has selenium and chromeWebDrive. I ran the following command to start the container.

`docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v ${PWD}:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome`

The selenium/standalone-chrome is the image I found from official seleniumHQ repo here
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

In my host machine, I have a test.py file that looks like this in vs-code.

`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`

However, I am getting warning from my vs-code saying `unresolved import selenium`

I don't have selenium installed in my host machine and I was hoping to use docker instead.

Is there a way to make my vs-code recognize the selenium package inside my docker? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a misunderstanding between chrome docker image and selenium module. Let me try to answer assuming this. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

> In my host machine, I have a test.py file that looks like this in vs-code.

In the line **from selenium import webdriver**, *selenium* is a python [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and *webdriver* is one of the module inside *selenium* package. This package must be installed, in your host machine or from wherever you are trying to invoke test.py, using *pip* command.

```
pip install selenium # python 2
pip3 install selenium # python 3
```

> docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v ${PWD}:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome

This command starts standalone chrome container which acts as a hub and node. Also please note that this container does not come with selenium package installed. You can view the sessions by loading http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html url in browser. An example test is given below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

desiredCapabilities={
"browserName":"chrome"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities = desiredCapabilities);

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Privacy')
ActionChains(driver) \
    .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
    .click(element) \
    .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
    .perform()
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Below are few links to get more details

1. Setup python -
   http://allselenium.info/python-selenium-webdriver-environment-setup/
2. Setup docker -
   http://allselenium.info/selenium-docker-parallel-execution-made-easy/
3. Debug docker -
   http://allselenium.info/how-to-debug-tests-running-on-docker-containers/

Hope this helps.